# Finding Modules with Given Length of Composition Series

Tags: modules

I study a course about commutative algebra, and I saw many questions as the following:

> Find an example of a $\mathbb{Q}\left[\lambda_1,\lambda_2\right]$-module with $\ell\left(M\right)=3$ (i.e., $M$ has a composition series of length 3.

Can you please help me find such an example? And do you have any guidelines about how to approach such a question?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know an example of a simple module? Do you know about direct sums?

Comment: There is a theorem stating that, is $S$ is a simple $R$-module, then the direct sum of $n$ copies of $S$ has an obvious composition series of length $n$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now :)